# .NET C# WPF DataGrid Как ускорить отрисовку?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется некий DataGrid:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="10,29,10,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <DataGrid x:Name="dgCatalog" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  IsReadOnly="False" Background="{x:Null}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MainExcelWorker.MainTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Есть `DataTable` с ~4000 строками, и что бы все сразу не не отрисовывать я разделил их на автогенерируемые таблички по 60 строк. Среди этих табличек (страниц) пользователь переходит стрелочками или сразу вводит номер нужной таблицы (страницы).И уж очень медленно компьютер отрисовывает строки этих табличек, примерно тратит 2-3+ секунды.

Вопрос в следующем, как можно ускорить отрисовку строк?

P.S. Не знаю нужна ли такая информация, но столбцов ~14.

Comment: У DataGrid же есть своя полоса прокрутку + виртуальный режим. Зачем Scroll Viewer, разделение на таблички?

Comment: Насчет ScrollViewer, если не мне не изменяет память, мне нужно было что бы полоса прокрутки была за DataGrid, а не "внутри".
Виртуальный режим как в WinForms? Как его включить?

Comment: Или Вы хотите сказать что из ScrollViewer скорость отрисовки упала?

Comment: Он по умолчанию включен. Но если вам не подходит встроенная полоса прокрутки, он не поможет.

Comment: А насчет того, зачем разделение на таблички, то если отрисовывать все 4000+ строк, то соответсвенно это совершено неприемлимо, а как-то по другому реализовать pager я не придумал.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.5.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина медленной отрисовки была в том, что `DataGrid` был помещен в `ScrollViewer`, из-за этого отрисовывались все 60 строк, в то время как если бы `ScrollViewer` небыло, отрисовались бы только те строки которые "помещались" в контейнер.